# Limit to the amount of options that can be created using Ruby's OptParse

Tags: ruby, argv, optparse

Due to the size of the program I will not be able to post all of it, please see the latest push [here](https://github.com/WhitewidowScanner/whitewidow)

I have a program that has around 15 option flags in it:

```
ARGV << '-h' if ARGV.empty? # Display help dialog if no flags are passed
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.banner = banner_message
  opt.on('-f FILE', '--file FILE', 'Pass a filename to scan for vulnerabilities')         { |o| OPTIONS[:file]    = o }
  opt.on('-s URL', '--spider URL', 'Spider a web page and save all the URLS')             { |o| OPTIONS[:spider]  = o }
  opt.on('-p IP:PORT', '--proxy IP:PORT', 'Configure to run with a proxy, must use ":"')  { |o| OPTIONS[:proxy]   = o }
  opt.on('-x NUM', '--run-x NUM', 'Run the specified amount of dry runs')                 { |o| OPTIONS[:run]     = o }
  opt.on('-D DORK', '--dork DORK', 'Use your own dork to do the searching')               { |o| OPTIONS[:dork]    = o } # Issue #32 https://github.com/Ekultek/whitewidow/issues/32
  opt.on('-c NAME', '--column NAME', 'Specify a column name to be run for union SQLi')    { |o| OPTIONS[:cols]    = o }
  opt.on('-d', '--default', 'Run in default mode, scrape Google')                         { |o| OPTIONS[:default] = o }
  opt.on('-l', '--legal', 'Show the legal information and the TOS')                       { |o| OPTIONS[:legal]   = o }
  opt.on('-b', '--banner', 'Hide the banner')                                             { |o| OPTIONS[:banner]  = o }
  opt.on('-v', '--version', 'Display the version number and exit')                        { |o| OPTIONS[:version] = o }
  opt.on('-u', '--update', 'Update whitewidow with the newest version')                   { |o| OPTIONS[:update]  = o }
  opt.on('--dry-run', 'Run a dry run (no checking for vulnerability with prompt)')        { |o| OPTIONS[:dry]     = o }
  opt.on('--batch', 'No prompts, used in conjunction with the dry run')                   { |o| OPTIONS[:batch]   = o }
  opt.on('--beep', 'Make a beep when the program finds a vulnerability')                  { |o| OPTIONS[:beep]    = o }
  opt.on('--rand-agent', 'Use a random user agent')                                       { |o| OPTIONS[:agent]   = o }
  opt.on('--sqlmap', 'Run sqlmap through the SQL_VULN.LOG file as a bulk file')           { |o| OPTIONS[:sqlmap]  = o }
  opt.on('--test', 'Used mostly for development use')                                     { |o| OPTIONS[:test]    = o }
  opt.on('-h', '--help', 'Display this help dialog and exit') do
    usage_page
    puts opt
  end
end.parse!
```

The newest option is the `-c` flag, what I'm trying to do is get the information from the `-c` flag and use it as the extraction point for the information, however, when I run the flag, it will only pull information from the file that is default:

```
#
# Decide whether to use random column names, or a specific one
#
def random_col_name?
  if OPTIONS[:cols]
    OPTIONS[:cols]
  else
    File.readlines("#{PATH}/lib/lists/common_columns.txt").sample
  end
end
```

For example:
`ruby program.rb -d -c test -D php?id=`
Will pull `http://www.bible-history.com/subcat.php?id=2` which is correct, put from there is should add the information from the `-c` flag to the end of it like so: `http://www.bible-history.com/subcat.php?id=2 test`. However all it does is add the information from the file: `http://www.bible-history.com/subcat.php?id=2 clave`. My question being, why is it that when I try to extract the information from the flag, it will not accept the `ARGV` and only reads from the file, is there a limit to the amount of options I can create?

Comment: There's no inherent limit to how many arguments you can make but presumably after you've exhausted all the single letters you're stuck with long versions. What's the problem here? Make sure all the appropriate blocks are firing correctly, like dump out your `options` before executing. This appears to be a debugging problem.

Comment: Where this `:cols` came from? The option name is `column`, isn’t it?

Comment: @tadman That makes sense, thank you

Comment: @mudasobwa the `[:cols]` comes from `{ |o| OPTIONS[:cols] = o }`

Comment: It's also worth noting that mutating what should be constant `OPTIONS` is also not a great plan. If you're intending to manipulate that, it should be a regular variable: `options`.